# Remove the node from source of UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiwebview

In my app, I am opening an URL in an UIWebView. I wanna remove a particular node in the page source. In the document.body, it has,

```
<div ui-view="navbar" class="ng-scope"><-></div>
<div ui-view="mainPanel" class="ng-scope"><-></div>
```

I want to completely remove the node which has `ui-view="navbar"`. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute arbitrary Javascript using the `UIWebView` method `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`

For example:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('div[ui-view=\"navbar\"]').remove();"];
```

Would remove the navbar node using jQuery. Apologies, I'm not familiar with Angular so I don't know the equivalent statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.querySelector` to find the node, then call `remove()` on it. This does not require any particular JavaScript library to be loaded (with `UIWebView` there is no possibility that the browser is too old to support it):

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(
  "document.querySelector('[ui-view=navbar]').remove();")
```

Or Objective-C:

```
(void) [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
        @"document.querySelector('[ui-view=navbar]').remove();"];
```